# Changing Card height and width

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set the height and width of a card like below, but it is returning error: "the named parameter is not defined" for both height and width. Is this an incorrect way to set card height and width?

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

```
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onBackPressed(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(
            'Finding your pizza',
            style: theme.textTheme.title,
          ),
        ),
        body: new Card(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/60,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/60,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: You can use the Card as a child of Container and set width, height for that Container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the [`Card`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html) class does not contain neither `height` nor `width` named parameter.

You can use a `Container` that will have both `height` and `width`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Card(
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
        onTap: () {
          print('Card tapped.');
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Text('A card that can be tapped'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a container is overkill, you may also use a `SizedBox` widget to set width and height as well.

```
final double cardWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/60;
final double cardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/60,
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
   SizedBox(
    width:  cardWidth,
    height: cardHeight,
    child: Card(child: Text('Hello World!')),
  ),
...
}
```